# Bin packing with fixed number of bins with differing capacities

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, packing, bin-packing

I'm working on a problem that involves having a fixed set of items that need to be packed into a fixed number of bins, each with a different capacities.

It's guaranteed that all the items can be packed into the fixed number of bins and there will be no capacity left over.

A good example of this would be having a finite number of coins and two different balances and trying to figure out which coins go into forming which balance.

I'm aware that bin packing is NP-hard, but I was wonder if there was a better approximate solution to this problem than the greedy algorithm I've been using.

Comment: Please outline the greedy algorithm you've been using.

Comment: Greedy algorithms can usually be improved significantly with appending them with Local Search. For example: see [this benchmark report](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/blog/2013-08-19/) (red and blue are greedy, others are greedy + local search) for the datasets of [Cloud balancing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhCtuM-Hiic) (which is a form of bin packing).

Comment: if its partial item filling like knapsack then greedy will do its job. I hardly think you would get any other better algo than being greedy. If its 0-1 knapsack then DP is there.